# Draw two line inside 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I've a 2D array with speific size (e.g. 50) filled with **.** (points), I'm tyring to understand this issue :

*The programs asks for the horizontal and vertical distances (these are 2 numbers) and the starting character, draws 2 “lines” into the array, starts from the lower-left and from the lower-right corner!
Then the program displays the array.*

```
   //We declare a 2D array with size of 50
   char[][] coordSystem = new char[50][50];

   //Fill the array with "." (point)
   for (int row = 0; row  <= coordSystem.length - 1; row ++) //first loop for row
      for (int col= 0; col<= coordSystem.length - 1; col++) //second loop for column
            coordSystem[row][col] = '.';

   // Our program asks for the horizontal and vertical distances and the starting character.
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Please type the horizontal distance : ");
   int horizontalDistance = scanner.nextInt();
   System.out.print("Please type the vertical distance : ");
   int verticalDistance = scanner.nextInt();
   System.out.print("Please type the starting character : ");
   char startChar = scanner.next().charAt(0);
```

output should look like this :
Example:

```
Please type the horizontal distance: 5
Please type the vertical distance: 2
Please type the starting character: E


....................I........I....................
..................................................
...............H..................H...............
..................................................
..........G............................G..........
..................................................
.....F......................................F.....
..................................................
E................................................E
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Good day, have you done the task? :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that horizontal distance is just distance that letter should "travell" after every iteration. And vertical distance is just how many rows you should skip. Starting character is just a letter, which will be written in the array and seems like after each iteration it should decrease in alphabetical order, while it doesn't become A, I suppose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've updated my question could you please check it (output)

Comment: Seems about right. Actually, I think I missed the point a bit. Line should be drawn until it hits the upper border, not until it the letter becomes an "A".